# Edge Browser Ajax file upload call WebApi is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Edge Browser Issue : Ajax Call to web API is not working in Edge browser, rest other browsers its working fine including IE.

```
function uploadPDFajaxcall(data, url) {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        //contentType: "application/json",
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);

        }
    });
}
```

Actual: Edge browser getting Error (catch). rest all browsers working as expected.

Expected: It should hit the web API successfully

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting? A little more information would be helpfull.

Comment: You can show us the error message for debug.